# Looking for YA short story about boy who finds family living in cave from alternate world

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, parallel-universe

I’m looking for the name of a YA short story that I read in middle school back in the late 70’s. I believe it was part of a Science Fiction short story collection. My recollection is that it had “Key” in the title, but it wasn’t Asimov’s short story. As I recall, a boy meets members of a family who live in a cave, and they are the last survivors of a group from another planet or parallel universe.

I don’t remember a lot of detail about the plot, and I was leary of including too much detail in case I’m not remembering it correctly. But I seem to recall that it had an “Escape to witch mountain “ vibe, where you meet these people with strange ways and a secretive past. It takes place on earth but they must have looked like the locals because it’s not revealed until the end that they are not from there.

Comment: Your description of the actual story is quite brief, can you remember anything else about it you can [edit] in?

Comment: Maybe related to [this](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/17301/story-about-people-living-in-a-cave-and-not-wanting-to-leave-and-explore)?